# can i use any object without alloc and init methods in iphone apps

Tags: ios4

I have just declared an NSString Object without using alloc and init methods. After that  i added the string to this newly created string Object, it  is working fine , why?
Code:

```
NSString *str;
str=@"Adding the data without allocating and initilizing object";
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The @"some string" method already creates a constant NSString for you. You created a pointer to a string in your first line and assigning it to point to newly created constant string in a second line.. This way is very common. Actually there are almost no cases you really need to call alloc, init on NSString.